# GEOSoft data analysis and processing

Tags: r, bioinformatics, ncbi

Is there any way to analyze the data within a `GEOSoft` file, from NCBI, in R?  I've tried converting it to an expression set, fitting it with `lmFit()`, then using `eBayes()`, but when I use `topTable()` to look at the results, the adjusted `P.Values` are always constant throughout the column.

Any help, or even pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: I'm assuming http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/r/geo/ didn't work?

Comment: Not quite.  I managed to get the 'eset' object using the methods there.  However, when I tried to analyze it, again, I got constant adjusted p values.  I'm wondering if there is any package, software, or set of methods available that are set up for use with GEOSoft files.  Failing that, is there an alternative way to analyze it?

Comment: Maybe the constant adjusted P-values are correct? The Bioconductor support site https://support.bioconductor.org might be an alternative and more appropriate forum for future posts.